# Protecting IIS7 with a simple username password

Tags: iis-7

Is it possible to protect certain folders or sites in IIS7 with a basic authentication user, that is NOT in windows. I tried adding users in the user manager and allowing them, but it does not accept the user.

I do not want to write a custom auth, I just want the same feature apache offers since version 0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box - some development, or use of another module, is required. Forms-based authentication is closest, but you'd need to establish the forms user identities, by default in the ASP.net membership database.

Alternatively, some assembly required:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/528/how-to-use-the-sample-read-only-xml-membership-and-role-providers-with-iis-70/

Or you could find a Basic authentication module that works against a simple list of usernames & passwords.

Like http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/170/developing-a-module-using-net/

Comment: Thanks, but some are normal folders with content and some others are website for customers, that's why it's a problem, cannot do anything in the code.

Comment: not in "the" website code, you'd create a module (or just enable Forms auth for random content) and plug it into the pipeline on the server, just like IIS does with all its components these days. Then it doesn't matter what content's in there, or what code it's going to execute. Or at least, not more than it would have if IIS did offer an option like that.